# implementing a linked list and it doesn't produce output

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list but it doesn't display any output.

implementing a linked list with 4 elements and making fuction insert and insertathead and display.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// class node to make node element.
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node{
    }
    // constructor
    node(int val)
    {
        data = val;
        next = NULL;
    }
     
    // function to insert element at head.
    void insertAthead(node *&head, int val)
    {
        node *n = new node(val);
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
        return;
    }

    // function to insert in linked list.
    void insert(node *head, int val)
    {
        node *temp = head;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            insertAthead(head, val);
            return;
        }
        node *n = new node(val);
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = n;
    }

    // function to display each element in a linked list.
    void display(node *head)
    {
        while (head->next != NULL)
        {
            cout << head->data;
            head = head->next;
        }
        cout << head->data;
    }
};

//main function 

int main()
{

    node *head;    // line at which I think there is a problem
    head->insert(head, 1);
    head->insert(head, 2);
    head->insert(head, 3);
    head->insert(head, 4);
    head->display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is at line 1

```
node *head;
```

when I change this line with `node *head=new node(any integer value)` the code runs fine.

Comment: Accessing `head->...` without initializing `head` is UB.

Comment: [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/) Because your compiler wants to tell you what the problem is, in less time than it takes to post a question.

Comment: Just as a side note: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/12149471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to move `insert`, `insertAtHead` and `display` out of the `Node` class. These are list functions have have no need of special access to `Node`.

Also you should initialise `head` to NULL (representing the empty list).

This means changing `main` like this

```
node *head = NULL;
insert(head, 1);
insert(head, 2);
insert(head, 3);
insert(head, 4);
display(head);
```

Then you want to change

```
void insert(node *head, int val)
```

to

```
void insert(node *&head, int val)
```

Just like you have done (correctly) with `insertAtHead`.

If you wanted to take this further you could create a List class, along these lines

```
class List
{
public:
    List() { root = NULL; }
    void insert(int val);
    void insertAtHead(int val);
    void display();
private:
    Node* root;
};
```

then main would look like this

```
int main()
{
    List l;
    l.insert(1);
    l.insert(2);
    l.insert(3);
    l.insert(4);
    l.display();
}
```

Comment: And if you are appending to the list then the list should keep track of the tail and not search for it on every insert.

Comment: I have a question can i Initialize head to NULL with constructor. Like earlier my code was  node *head;                           can i make a constructor that automatically initializes this head to NULL.

Comment: @MohammedfaizKhan You cannot write a constructor for a pointer because a pointer is not a class. But you can put a pointer in a class and write a constructor that sets the pointer inside the class to NULL. That's what I did with my List class above.

Comment: Thanks john, thanks for helping I'm kinda new to C++ and I'm finding this pointer part very difficult.

Comment: @MohammedfaizKhan That's a very common feeling. It clicks eventually.